# Can I reprogram my key which lost sync to unlock lock car? Car starts

Tags: mercedes-benz, fob

I own a 2006 Mercedes C280 I have two keys which once upon a time they both started the car and lock and unlock the car now one key doesn’t work at all since I haven’t used it in over six months I had a dead battery and the other key does start the car but for some reason it doesn’t lock and unlock my doors

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken and there is a DIY way of doing this, I think you're going to have to take it to your MB dealer and pay their "premium" labor rates to fix this problem.

Comment: A cheaper option is to contact a locksmith who does cars.

Comment: Perhaps just the battery too, if enough juice to control the starting circuit, but not the locking. Step 1 is change the battery. Aside: when I broke a key, the (Skoda) dealer was a *much* more expensive option than the local key/heel bar, and would have taken 2 weeks instead of 2 hours.

Comment: Have you replaced the battery in the key fob (and is that the battery that was dead, or was it your car's battery)?